# Error using tables in officer: "no applicable method for 'ph_with' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"

Tags: r, officer

I've been trying to generate powerpoint slides with officer and ran into the following Error:

```
Error in UseMethod("ph_with", value) : 
  no applicable method for 'ph_with' applied to an object of class "c('xml_document', 'xml_node')"
```

I can reproduce the error with the example on https://davidgohel.github.io/officer/articles/offcran/tables.html, so I assume it is not something wrong with my code.

I'm on R 3.6.0.

Comment: It maybe an issue with your packages versions. Could you check you have the latest version of package officer and flextable?

Comment: Thanks @DavidGohel, I updated a whole bunch of packages in my installation, and used the github version of officeR. This seems to have done the trick.

Comment: cool. CRAN version of officer should also works :)